# What coverage criteria are implemented in LLVM Code Coverage / Slather?

Tags: ios, format, llvm, code-coverage, criteria

I'm using [LLVM Code Coverage](http://llvm.org/docs/CoverageMappingFormat.html) to determine the code coverage of my iOS app's source code, and after that generate a report using [Slather](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather).

I was wondering which of the criteria listed at the code [coverage wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage), however I have trouble finding this information.

In other words; what criteria does LLVM Code Coverage Mapping Format (or Slather) use to determine the code coverage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLVM Coverage is at the finer of the wikipedia list, i.e. the condition level.

For example here: http://lab.llvm.org:8080/coverage/coverage-reports/clang/coverage/Users/buildslave/jenkins/sharedspace/clang-stage2-coverage-R@2/llvm/tools/clang/lib/CodeGen/BackendUtil.cpp.html#L659

You can mouse over each side of the condition line 664 and see how many times each was evaluated.

Comment: Are there ways to find out which coverage criteria are met?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I have a iOS codebase, and I'd like to test it to the criteria as listed on the wiki page (condition coverage, decision coverage etc.). I was wondering how to go about this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this maybe? http://lab.llvm.org:8080/coverage/coverage-reports/clang/index.html